# Dll in C++ 2013 needst to return a string to VB.net

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net, string, dll

I am puzzled... i am a VB.net programmer and I need to create an interface with a receiver. Sending data to the receiver is no problem, i can program the frequency, bandwith and stuff like that... I am obliged to use C++ to talk to the receiver. So I decided to give it a shot and create a dll in C++ and make the GUI in VB.net. However, when I want to ask info from the receiver, I got stuck...

My C++ code looks like this

```
char __stdcall Q_BW(){
    MyPR100::sendSCPI(TCPsock, "SENS:BAND?\n");
    char pRxBuf[256];
    int len = recv(TCPsock, pRxBuf, sizeof(pRxBuf), 0);
    if (len < 0) len = 0; pRxBuf[len] = '\0';
    puts(pRxBuf);
    return  pRxBuf;
}
```

So basically, sending a command to the receiver, and putting the result into a buffer... now this buffer needs to be returned to VB.net and this is where I fail...
When I compile, I have the error

Cannot convert from 'char[256]' to 'char'

I can see what I am doing wrong, but apparently I am unable to find a solution for this... The dll is working fine for sending data to the receiver, so that part is working...
To be complete, this is the VB.net code...

```
 Private Declare Function Q_BW Lib "PR100Dll.dll" () As String

Dim Res As String = ""
Res = Q_BW()
MsgBox(Res, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

I know this might be a rookie question, but I am really stuck here... Since I am not that good (which is an uderstatement) in C++, and English is not my native language, I would be happy if I got a not so difficult answer where I can learn of... Oh, please do note the I have been googling for 2 weeks now and that I am really at the end...

thanks in advance...

Comment: A `String` in VB.NET maps to a [BSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069.aspx) in unmanaged code. Unless you are reading UTF-16 encoded characters in your `recv` call, you need to convert the data to UTF-16.

Comment: `char __stdcall Q_BW()` returns a single charachter, not a string. Also for interaction with VB you'll need a `bstr_t` which is completely different from a `char*` or `std::string`.

Comment: Can I have some examples please? that would be very greatful....

Comment: I was to late to add my example... If I change it to BSTR __stdcall Q_BW() then I get the error that it wants a semi-colon before the stdcall.... I am really baffled here.....

Comment: That's **one** of the errors you get. Another one is that the `BSTR` type is unknown (and that's what's causing it). Besides, simply changing the return type won't do anything to solve your issue. `BSTR`s have different semantics, too. I provided a link in my first comment. It doesn't appear like you are prepared for the complexity of the problem (and solution). There's **lots** more to consider (like character encoding, potential conversion, or maybe use of another container type altogether, in case it cannot be converted).

Comment: I am prepared, but as said before, english is not my mother language, wich complicates it, and there are a lot of terms I am not familiar with. Thats why I asked for small examples.... after all, I am a VB.net programmer and know virtually nothing about C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote one example for you:

1.TestDll.cpp (The function in dll)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

char* __stdcall ReadString()
{
    return "ABCDEFG";
}
```

2.TestDll.def (Export the ReadString function)

```
LIBRARY     TestDll
EXPORTS
    ReadString
```

3.TestCS (CSharp demo)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestCS
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("TestDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern IntPtr ReadString();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr t = ReadString();
            String result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(t);
        }
    }
}
```

4.TestVB (VB demo)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    Private Declare Function ReadString Lib "TestDll.dll" () As IntPtr

    Sub Main()
        Dim t As IntPtr
        Dim result As String

        t = ReadString
        result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(t)
    End Sub

End Module
```

You should set the same charset in dll project and CS project and VB project.

Comment: you are awesome... today I was ill and stayed home from work, but I sure will try this on monday! Thanks for the clear example. Now I can dig in a bit deeper.